# How to interpret [p in keyof T] and T[p] in these TypeScript declarations?

Tags: typescript, ngrx

I am reading ***ngrx*** docs and stumbled upon such a code. What do `[p in keyof T]` and `T[p]` mean?

```
export type ActionReducerMap<T, V extends Action = Action> = {
  [p in keyof T]: ActionReducer<T[p], V>
};
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is a mapped type. You can read about them in the typescript docs [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), or in this [blog post](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/01/20/typescript-2-1-mapped-types).

Basically, the syntax `[p in keyof T]` means just that; `p` is one of the keys of the object `T`. Then, the `T[p]` just represents the type of that key's value. Read those two links for a more robust explanation.

Comment: And what is the difference if we change it to `[p extends keyof T] `?